# NoHandlerForCommandException with axon-spring-boot-starter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cqrs, axon, spring-boot-starter

I am creating a simple app using Axon + Spring Boot, just to make sure I understand the basic components in Axon framework before I use it in a real project. 
There is a method annotated with @CommandHandler within the class TaskAggregate that is supposed to be called when I send a command through the CommandGateway, but after running the app I am getting the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.axonframework.commandhandling.NoHandlerForCommandException: No handler was subscribed to command [com.xxx.axontest.task.CreateTaskCommand]
```

As per the documentation, the @CommandHandler annotation should be enough to subscribe the command hander to the command bus. I guess I must be missing something. Could you take a look to below code and point me to the right direction?.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>axon-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <axon.version>3.0.6</axon.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>axon-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>${axon.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

App.java

```
package com.xxx.axontest;

import org.axonframework.commandhandling.gateway.CommandGateway;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.EventStorageEngine;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.inmemory.InMemoryEventStorageEngine;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import com.xxx.axontest.task.CreateTaskCommand;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext = SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
        CommandGateway commandGateway = configurableApplicationContext.getBean(CommandGateway.class);
        commandGateway.send(new CreateTaskCommand(123, "asd"));
    }

    @Bean
    public EventStorageEngine eventStorageEngine() {
        return new InMemoryEventStorageEngine();
    }

    @Bean
    public AnnotationCommandHandlerBeanPostProcessor 
 annotationCommandHandlerBeanPostProcessor() {
    return new AnnotationCommandHandlerBeanPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

CreateTaskCommand.java

```
package com.xxx.axontest.task;

import org.axonframework.commandhandling.TargetAggregateIdentifier;

public class CreateTaskCommand {

    @TargetAggregateIdentifier
    private int taskId;
    private String name;

    public CreateTaskCommand(int taskId, String name) {
        this.taskId = taskId;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getTaskId() {
        return taskId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }   
}
```

TaskCreatedEvent.java

```
package com.xxx.axontest.task;

import org.axonframework.commandhandling.TargetAggregateIdentifier;

public class TaskCreatedEvent {

    @TargetAggregateIdentifier
    private int taskId;
    private String name;

    public int getTaskId() {
        return taskId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

TaskAggregate.java

```
package com.xxx.axontest.task;

import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.axonframework.commandhandling.CommandHandler;
import org.axonframework.commandhandling.model.AggregateIdentifier;
import org.axonframework.commandhandling.model.AggregateLifecycle;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.EventSourcingHandler;
import org.axonframework.spring.stereotype.Aggregate;

@AggregateRoot
public class TaskAggregate {

    private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(TaskCreatedEvent.class);

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private int taskId;
    private String name;

    @CommandHandler
    public void handleCommand(CreateTaskCommand createTaskCommand) {
        logger.info("Command received");
        AggregateLifecycle.apply(new TaskCreatedEvent());
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void onTaskCreatedEvent(TaskCreatedEvent taskCreatedEvent) {
        logger.info("Event received");
    }

    public int getTaskId() {
        return taskId;
    }

    public void setTaskId(int taskId) {
        this.taskId = taskId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One important thing: events and commands should be immutable (no setters)

Comment: From doc: "CommandHandlers need to be subscribed to a CommandBusin order to receive command"

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu, I removed the setters following your recommendation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to annotate your aggregate with @Aggregate rather than `@AggregateRoot`.
`@Aggregate` as an annotation is both the `@AggregateRoot` annotation, but is also used by the Spring Boot Axon Starter module to signal that for that class an Aggregate factory and `Repository` has to be created.
Additionally, that'll mean the `@CommandHandler` annotated functions on your aggregate will also be found and registered to the `CommandBus`, probably solving the exception you caught.

Otherwise, the [webinars](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2zH7BsqtAk) on YouTube from Allard for starting an Axon application in version 3 could give you some insight.

But, in short, try switching the `@AggregateRoot` annotation for `@Aggregate` :-)

Additionally however, you should be adjusting the `@CommandHandler` annotated function for the `CreateTaskCommand` to be a constructor for the `TaskAggregate`.
Lastly, Axon requires you to have a no-arg constructor for you aggregate, so also add a `public TaskAggregate() { }` constructor in there.

Comment: Good catch. I tried that and now I am getting **Command 'com.xxx.axontest.task.CreateTaskCommand' resulted in org.axonframework.commandhandling.model.AggregateNotFoundException(The aggregate was not found in the event store)**

Comment: Adjusted the comment to point out that you should probably have the `CreateTaskCommand` be handled by a constructor rather than a regular function. And additionally, also a no-arg constructor, as Axon requires that.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem when running tests. There is an aggregate that works fine but another is not discovered... I used the same annotation @Aggragate, empty constructor and commandHandler constructor. It is registered when the application runs but not when running tests. Any idea? thanks

Comment: What kind of tests are you pointing at @Pietro? For Aggregate tests, Axon provides dedicated test fixtures I would recommend you use. You can find more on them here: https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/testing/commands-events

Comment: If it's an integration test using Spring Boot, you will have to make sure the required Axon components are wired, as well as the components containing the command handling functions.

Comment: I'm using the fixture of Axon and the components are wired because the application runs without problems. Here is the test that is not working https://github.com/gpietro/spring-boot-cqrs-demo/blob/master/src/test/java/com/fundev/adt/command/PatientTest.java#L60.
All the tests pointing to the EpisodeOfCare (https://github.com/gpietro/spring-boot-cqrs-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fundev/adt/command/EpisodeOfCare.java#L34) commandHandlers are not found. The logged error is: No handler was subscribed to command [com.fundev.adt.coreapi.CommandPatientAdmit]

Comment: Ah, well a Test Fixture only deals with a single Aggregate type, not with several. Your test however uses an `AggregateTestFixture` for the `Patient` aggregate type. If you want to test the `EpisodeOfCare` aggregate too, you will have to define a different `AggregateTestFixture` for that aggregate. I would recommend to add a distinct `EpisodeOfCareTest` class which creates the test fixture for the `EpisodeOfCare`, segregated from the `PatientTest`.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the above code, a few remarks:

- you do not need to provide a AnnotationCommandHandlerBeanPostProcessor. In fact, specifying one may interfere with the regular operation of Axon/Spring Boot autoconfiguration
- The commands that creates a new Aggregate instance should be placed on a constructor. The is no instance to invoke the method on, yet. Note that you will (also) have to specify a no-arg constructor.
- The taskId should be set by the @EventSourcingHandler. Getters and Setters do not belong in an (event sourced) Aggregate
- In Events, you do not need to specify @TargetAggregateIdentifier. They are only means for commands.

I can't explain this exception given the code you provide, but there is a chance that the explicitly defined AnnotationCommandHandlerBeanPostProcessor is in the way.

[Edited] Steven correctly noted the @AggregateRoot annotation. It should be @Aggregate. Above comments are still valid, but not directly related to the exception [/Edited]

Comment: A little bit confused because the [documentation](https://docs.axonframework.org/v/3.0/part3/spring-boot-autoconfig.html) says: **Axon will automatically register all the CommandHandler annotated methods with the Command Bus and set up a repository if none is present.** without mentioning constructors. But using the @CommandHandler annotation in the constructor instead of a method,  as you suggested, fixed the problem.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to register your handler to the command bus. I found [this tutorial](http://www.geekabyte.io/2015/10/exploring-cqrs-with-axon-framework.html?m=1) that should help you. A quick highlight from there:

```
@Configuration 
public class AppConfiguration { 

    @Bean  
    public SimpleCommandBus commandBus() { 
        SimpleCommandBus simpleCommandBus = new SimpleCommandBus(); 
        // This manually subscribes the command handler: 
        // DebitAccountHandler to the commandbus.  
        simpleCommandBus.subscribe(DebitAccount.class.getName(), new DebitAccountHandler()); 
        return simpleCommandBus;  
    }
}
```

*P.S. One important thing: events and commands should be immutable (no setters)*

Comment: The tutorial you mention is using axon 2.4.1. I am using 3.0.6. In [axon's documentation](https://docs.axonframework.org/v/3.0/part3/spring-boot-autoconfig.html), section Aggregate Configuration, they say: **Axon will automatically register all the @CommandHandler annotated methods with the Command Bus and set up a repository if none is present.**

Comment: In the tutorial you mention they also say:
**if using Axon with Spring, use the AnnotationCommandHandlerBeanPostProcessor which allows us to have Spring beans that have methods annotated with @CommandHandler be turned into a command handler.**

Comment: In my project the command handler is within the aggregate. In axon 3.0.6 there is not CommandHandler interface I could inherit from.

Answer (score 1):

> Bases on the comments

I will like to share the modified actual code.

```
@Aggregate
public class TaskAggregate {

    private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(TaskCreatedEvent.class);

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private int taskId;

    private String name;

    TaskAggregate(){ // default constructor needed for axon
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public void TaskAggregate(CreateTaskCommand createTaskCommand) {
        logger.info("Command received");
        AggregateLifecycle.apply(new TaskCreatedEvent());
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void onTaskCreatedEvent(TaskCreatedEvent taskCreatedEvent) {
        logger.info("Event received");
        this.name = taskCreatedEvent; // use this to set the aggregate meber than get and setter.
    }

}
```

**@CommandHandler** annotated function for the **CreateTaskCommand** to be a constructor for the **TaskAggregate**. Lastly, Axon requires you to have a **no-arg constructor** for you aggregate, so also add a public **TaskAggregate()** { } constructor in there.